# Two questions-order of bar plots and getting discrete scale to show up on axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

1.The y axis label is disappearing when I try and add breaks or limits.  I tried converting the data to a factor, but that does not seem to help (maybe I'm missing something?).
2. Also for some reason the bars flip so that sometimes the drinking bar is on the right and sometimes it is on the left of the recreation bar.  I want all drinking/recreation bars on the same side.

I have tried organizing my data differently (data below shown in current csv format), I have tried continuous and discrete scales. When I try a continuous scale I get the error "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

```
Media              Method       Percent
Workshops           Recreation  0%
Conferences         Recreation  37%
Press Release       Recreation  47%
Website             Recreation  21%
Brochures           Recreation  43%
Public Meetings     Recreation  33%
Mailers             Recreation  8%
Social Media        Recreation  55%
Posters             Recreation  43%
Veterinary Outreach Recreation  43%
Health Outreach     Recreation  25%
Other               Recreation  24%
Workshops           Drinking    32%
Conferences         Drinking    34%
Press Release       Drinking    30%
Website             Drinking    28%
Brochures           Drinking    19%
Public Meetings     Drinking    17%
Mailers             Drinking    13%
Social Media        Drinking    9%
Posters             Drinking    9%
Veterinary Outreach Drinking    6%
Health Outreach     Drinking    4%
Other               Drinking    19%
```

## This works but the scale is weird. I don't understand why it got organized in this way[image]

```
 ggplot(data=outreach, aes(x=Media, y=Percent, fill=Method)) +     
    theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, size = 8, hjust = 1)) +  
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

## The y axis dissapears, so I tried adding in factor and that just gets added to my axis labels

```
 ggplot(data=outreach, aes(x=Media, y=factor(Percent),   
    fill=factor(Method)) + theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, size = 8, hjust = 1)) +  
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=seq(0,100,5))
```

Comment: In the future you can make it easier for us to help you by posting code to create a data set, as I did in the answer below. Usually it's best not to post your whole data set, but subset of it that is as minimal as possible while still working in your question.

Comment: thank you @ Gregory

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited my answer to give a little more clarity about how character strings with numbers are sorted. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the data type you're using to represent "Percent". It's a number, but because of the percentage symbol it's being handled as a character string. You can convert it into a factor as you did, but that doesn't really make sense because it is a *continuous numeric variable* and not a *discrete categorical variable*.

In short, character strings with numbers sort alphabetically and not numerically. For example:

```
sort(c("1", "2", "10", "12"))
# [1] "1"  "10" "12" "2"
```

In the example below, I used the `str_remove_all` from the package stringr to strip the percentage signs from that column, then converted it to a numeric data type.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

outreach <- tribble(~Media, ~Method, ~Percent,
"Workshops",           "Recreation",  "0%",
"Conferences",         "Recreation",  "37%",
"Press Release",       "Recreation",  "47%",
"Website",             "Recreation",  "21%",
"Brochures",           "Recreation",  "43%",
"Public Meetings",     "Recreation",  "33%",
"Mailers",             "Recreation",  "8%",
"Social Media",        "Recreation",  "55%",
"Posters",             "Recreation",  "43%",
"Veterinary Outreach", "Recreation",  "43%",
"Health Outreach",     "Recreation",  "25%",
"Other",               "Recreation",  "24%",
"Workshops",           "Drinking",    "32%",
"Conferences",         "Drinking",    "34%",
"Press Release",       "Drinking",    "30%",
"Website",             "Drinking",    "28%",
"Brochures",           "Drinking",    "19%",
"Public Meetings",     "Drinking",    "17%",
"Mailers",             "Drinking",    "13%",
"Social Media",        "Drinking",    "9%",
"Posters",             "Drinking",    "9%",
"Veterinary Outreach", "Drinking",    "6%",
"Health Outreach",     "Drinking",    "4%",
"Other",               "Drinking",    "19%"
)

outreach$Percent <- outreach$Percent %>%
  str_remove_all("%") %>%
  as.numeric()

ggplot(data=outreach, aes(x=Media, y=Percent, fill=Method)) +     
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, size = 8, hjust = 1)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]